# Solving the initial value problem which is given as follows

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$z'=z(z-5)(z-20)$$ where $z(3)=10.$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} z(x)=? $

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{dz}{z(z-5)(z-20)}=dx$$ taking integral and using the initial condition, I found

$\frac{z^3(z-20)}{(z-5)^4}=-16e^{300x-900}$.

(it may be wrong)
And then ?

Comment: Do you mean $z(3) = 10$, rather than $z(3) = 100$?  If it's really $z(3) = 100$, then your solution doesn't obey the initial condition;  but it does if you want $z(3) = 10$.

Comment: Dear Michael , you are right. z(3)=10. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $z_\infty = \lim_{x\to\infty} z(x)$.  We currently have a relationship of the form
$$
\frac{z^3(20-z)}{(z-5)^4} = 16 e^{300x-900}.
$$
If we take the limit as $x \to \infty$ on both sides, then $z \to z_\infty$ on the left-hand side, and we conclude that
$$
\lim_{z \to z_\infty}  \frac{z^3(20-z)}{(z-5)^4} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 16 e^{300x - 900}.
$$
This then allows us to figure out what $z_\infty$ is, via a two-step process:

- What is the limit on the right-hand side of this equation?
- At what values of $z$ does the quantity on the left-hand side approach this same limit?

I'll leave it there, since I don't want to solve your homework for you, but feel free to ask additional questions in the comments.

Comment: I haven' t heard a expression as yours up to now :) I mean the following notation $z\rightarrow z_\infty$ in the equation $
\lim_{z \to z_\infty}  \frac{z^3(20-z)}{(z-5)^4} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 16 e^{300x - 900}.
$ This is first :) There is no another way to solve?

Comment: @HD239:  There might be another, more rigorous way to solve it;  I'm honestly not sure.  (I'm a physics prof., not a math prof., so we tend to play fast & loose with notation.)  In principle you could solve for $z(x)$ explicitly, but it would involve finding the roots of a quartic polynomial, and the resulting functional form would almost certainly be unilluminating.

Answer (score 1):

You have an autonomous dynamical system on the line. From the equation you see that the fixed points $0,5,20$ lead to constant solutions that can not be crossed due to uniqueness.

On the intervals separated by the stationary points any solution stays inside these intervals and is monotonous. Falling on $(-\infty,0)$, growing on $(0,5)$, again falling on $(5,20)$ and growing again on $(20,\infty)$.

From this qualitative analysis one finds that the solution with $z(3)=10$ follows an inverted sigmoid curve falling from $z(-\infty)=20$ to $z(\infty)=5$.